# empty tableview cell for at index path row is not called

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

All the tableview functions are working except cell for row index path .

The problem maybe that foods array is empty so the number for rows is 0 so the cell for row at index path is not called

```
@IBOutlet weak var foooods: UITableView!
var databaseref = Database.database().reference()
var img : AnyObject?
var foods = [String?]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.databaseref.child("basic food").observe(.childAdded, with: {( snap: DataSnapshot) in
        let snapp = snap.value as! [String:AnyObject]
        if let x = snapp["name"] as! String? {
            self.foods.insert(x, at: 0)
            //self.foods.append(x)
        }
    })
    self.foooods.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.foods.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("difufuehf")
    let cell : foodsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "aupa", for:indexPath) as! foodsTableViewCell
    print("fufvksdfvysdgfvjdsgfdsygfvds,jhvjsdvsdjvguydsfgdsylfgdsyfgsdlygfsiygf")
    if let foo =  foods[indexPath.row]  {
        print(foo)
        cell.food.text = foo
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You are calling `reloadData` outside of the completion block instead of inside.

Comment: Its worth noting that if the completion block runs on a background queue, you should dispatch the reload onto the main queue.

Comment: i puted it  after insert rows  it gives me a sigbart

Comment: Why is `foods` and array of optional strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be a duplicate but I can't find one.

Your issue is that you call `reloadData` in the wrong place which results in it being called far too soon. You need to call it inside the completion block, after you update your data model.

And you need to make sure it gets called on the main queue.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.databaseref.child("basic food").observe(.childAdded, with: {( snap: DataSnapshot) in
        if let snapp = snap.value as? [String:Any], let x = snapp["name"] as? String {
            self.foods.insert(x, at: 0)
            //self.foods.append(x)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.foooods.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Note that I also fixed the way the value is obtained. You really need to avoid force unwrapping and force casting.

Comment: i added this but there is a sigbart error i tried to know which line but the cell at row func is called

Comment: Glad it worked. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your issues. It lets people know your question has been solved.